# Unable to Issue Tax Receipts

Tags: cdn-tax-receipts

another newbie question :)

I am trying to issue tax receipts using the action "Issue Tax Receipts (separate receipt for each contribution).  When I submit this, it generates a pdf of receipts for individuals with no email, but then I get the following 2 error messages:

[image]

So the receipt info is not being recorded on the contributions (they still show as no tax receipt issued) and the email receipt is not being sent.  I also tried issuing the receipt directly from the contribution itself and got the same mailing error.  Not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: Are any emails working in civi? What do you have at Administer - System Settings - Outbound Email, and if you use the Send Test button there? Or go to Contacts - New Email.

Comment: Also what do you have for the email settings at the bottom of Administer - CiviContribute - CDN Tax Receipts? Are those valid emails?

Comment: @Demerit Thanks - it looks like my IP address needs to setup with our API key for outbound mail (the test email also failed with that error message)